# Laravel : CRUD update a form

Tags: php, laravel

I will wish in fact to learn to update my data on Laravel. I am able to recuperate the ID with the informations from recording but when I change several  elements on my form and that I confirm.

I have a problem concerning **Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection methodNotAllowed** the error message is Auth::routes();
route::resource('student','AdminController');

My level is yet slow to understand the problem... What should I do ?

For information here is my code

I have a file named AdminController

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $students = Student::paginate(5);
      return view('student.index', compact('students'))
             ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('student.create');

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'firstname' => 'required',
                'lastname' => 'required'
        ]);

        Student::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('student.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $student = Student::find($id);
        return view('student.edit', compact('student'));

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'firstname' => 'required',
                'lastname' => 'required'
        ]);

        $student = Student::find($id);
        $student->firstname = $request->get('firstname');
        $student->lastname = $request->get('lastname');
        $student->save();

        return redirect()->route('student.index')
                  ->with('success', 'updated successfully');

    }

}
```

In View I have a folder nammed Student with 2 files

**index.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
      <div class="px-content">
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-xs-center text-md-left text-nowrap">
                    <h1>
                        <i class="px-nav-icon ion-android-apps"></i>List
                    </h1>
                </div>

                <hr class="page-wide-block visible-xs visible-sm">
                <!-- Spacer -->
                <div class="m-b-2 visible-xs visible-sm clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="{{ route('student.create') }}">Create</a>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Firstname</th>
                                    <th>Lastname</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            @foreach($students as $student)
                                <tr>
                                    <td> {{$student->firstname}}</td>
                                    <td> {{$student->lastname}} </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{route('student.edit',$student->id)}}">Edit</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!! $students->links() !!}
    </div>
@endsection
```

And also **edit.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
    <div class="px-content">
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-xs-center text-md-left text-nowrap">
                    <h1>
                        <i class="px-nav-icon ion-android-apps"></i>Edit {{$student->id}}
                    </h1>
                </div>

                <hr class="page-wide-block visible-xs visible-sm">
                <!-- Spacer -->
                <div class="m-b-2 visible-xs visible-sm clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <form class="panel-body" action="/student/edit/{{$student->id}}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label for="form-group-input-1">Firstname</label>
                                <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$student->firstname}}">
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <label for="form-group-input-1">Lastname</label>
                                <input type="text" name="valeur" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$lastname->valeur}}">
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <label for="form-group-input-1">Page</label>
                                <input type="text" name="page" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$tariff->page}}">
                            </fieldset>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">MAJ</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Concerning the folder route I have that

```
Auth::routes();
route::resource('student','AdminController');
```

Do you have an idea please ? Because I don't understand my problem...

Comment: Change method="POST" to PUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the below code in your blade after your `<form>`

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

and also change your route with `Route::PATCH('/update/{id}','YourController@update');`

Answer (score 4):

inside your form add this line anywhere

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a resource for the routes, your update route will have method `PUT|PATCH` so in order to be able to make a `put` request in your form inside `edit.blade.php` you are missing

`@method('PUT')`

keep in mind that the `method` tag on your form should remain `POST` this is an additional field.

And please everyone read some documentation before you answer
https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score -1):

in your edit.blade.php file you use POST method for form tag.  You should change it to PUT

```
<form class="panel-body" action="/student/edit/{{$student->id}}" method="POST">
```

change it to

```
<form class="panel-body" action="/student/edit/{{$student->id}}" method="PUT">
```

Because route::resource() generate PUT mathod route for update.

Comment: if this answer solved your problem please mark this answer as accpet